# Calling A Function From a Controller AngularJs Ionic

Tags: function, methods, angularjs

I am trying to call a function from my controller, but I keep getting:

```
TypeError: AuthService.login is not a function
```

My code is as follows:
controller.js

```
angular.module('starter')
        .controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope','$state','$ionicPopup','AuthService',function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService) {

            //declare scope.data.
            $scope.data = {};

        console.log(AuthService);
        $scope.login = function()
        {


            AuthService.login($scope.data.username,$scope.data.password).then(function(authenticated)
            {
                console.log('yes');

            },
            function(err)
            {
                console.log('no');
            });
        }






}]);
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter')
    .service('AuthService', function($q, $http) {

        var login = function login(name, pw)
        {
            console.log(name,pw);

        };

});
```

Comment: missing config ? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 1):

Your service isn't structured properly.  `var login = function ...` is creating a local variable, but isn't exposing it to the caller.  try `this.login = function ...` instead.